# a good way to validate the URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am using `React Native` `Linking` and `Fetch`.  Via the code below I open an URL (http://fixer.io).
I need to detect if the URL exists. I want to detect it before opening it and show an error to the user that the URL doesn't exist anymore.

```
 Linking.canOpenURL('http://fixer.io').then(supported => {
            if (!supported) {
                console.log(1);
            } else {
                fetch('http://fixer.io')
                    .then(() => Linking.openURL('http://fixer.io'))
                    .catch(() => console.log(2));

            }
        }).catch(err => console.log(3));
```

So if the URL doesn't exist for instance it's `http://fiiiiixer.io` the `fetch` will get it and `2` is logged, and if the URL is totally wrong like: `saddsa.fixer.io` that `canOpenURL` caches that and `1` will be shown.

Is it a good way to validate the URL? or is there any simpler way?

Answer (score 0):

Using fetch to attempt to retrieve the url is a good approach. If the status code is 404 you will know the url is not correct.